# Is it possible to reference a foreign key to parent table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE Product 
(
    "Product_id" int,
    "Stock_quantity" int,
    "Product_name" varchar(50),
    "Model" varchar(50),
    "Average_rating" float(3),
    "RAM" int,
    "Color" varchar(20),
    "Price" float(10),
    PRIMARY KEY ("Product_id")
);

CREATE TABLE Sale 
(
    "Sale_id" int,
    "Sale_date" date,
    "Employee_id" int,
    "Customer_id" int,
    "Product_id" int,
    "Product_quantity" int,
    "Rating" int,
    PRIMARY KEY ("Sale_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("Employee_id") REFERENCES Employee("Employee_id") ,
    FOREIGN KEY("Customer_id") REFERENCES Customer("Customer_id") ,
    FOREIGN KEY("Product_id") REFERENCES Product("Product_id")
);

CREATE TABLE Computer  
(
    "Type" varchar(10),
    "Processor" varchar(20),
    "Monitor_size" int
)  inherits(Product);

CREATE TABLE Mobile 
(
    "Os" varchar(30),
    "Screen_size" int
) inherits(Product);
```

Here is my tables while insertion of sale rows I get this error.

> ERROR: insert or update on table "sale" violates foreign key constraint "PK_Product_id"
>   SQL state: 23503
>   Detail: Key (Product_id)=(12) is not present in table "product".

It says there is no presence of the row, but I can see them when I view the table:

[image: However pgAdmin claims that there is no rows at table.]

I inserted every product as computer or mobile not as product.

Comment: Does product id 12 exists in product table?

Comment: could it be that you use different sessions? and you did not commit your changes?

Comment: It exists in product table when i view it with pgAdmin, but i can't reference them.

Comment: Re-validate with the session as pointed out by @Nerevar, It could be a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stumbling over one of the many quirks with inheritance: There are no “global” constraints on an inheritance hierarchy, consequently you cannot have a foreign key to a inheritance hierarchy.

The primary key you defined on `product` does *not* extend to `computer`.

Even though a `SELECT` on `product` will append the results for the inheritance children as well, these are not part of the table `parent` and consequently cannot be used as target for the foreign key. The foreign key is between `sale` and `product` *only*, the inheritance children are excluded.

There is no proper way to do this with inheritance.

It is better for `computer` *not* to be an inheritance child of product, but to have a foreign key to `product` (with a unique constraint on it), so that the data for a computer object will be split between the two tables. This is somewhat inconvenient for queries, but you can have a foreign key that way.

Here is an example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (
   product_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   prodname text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE computer (
   product_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   processor text NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id)
);

CREATE TABLE sale (
   sale_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   product_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES product(product_id)
);
```

Now there is no direct foreign key reference from `sale` to `computer`, but since the `product_id` of `computer` and `product` is identical, you can always find the unique computer for a `sale` if it exists:

```
SELECT p.prodname, c.processor
FROM sale s
   JOIN product p USING (product_id)
   LEFT JOIN computer c USING (product_id)
WHERE sale_id = 42;
```

If you have more product “subtypes”, you can add more left joins.

Comment: But how do you reference from `Sale` to specific product table?

Comment: Via the `product` table. You have a unique constraint on the source of the foreign key constraint from `computer` to `product`, so you can join the three tables to find the unique `computer` record that belongs to a given `sale`.

Comment: I'm sorry, still don't grab it. In `Sale`-table you have then `product_id` which references to `product` table and there is product type. But in `Sale` table you have sold certain phone or computer, you have to reference to specific table too somehow. I can see how to do it without constraints (like combining `product_type` and `item_id`), but how to costraint it on DB level?It really tortures me, I have pretty same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/q/50378680/196241

Comment: I have added an example to illustrate my idea.

Comment: OK, if I understand correctly, all subproducts share same pool of IDs? Those are PKs of Product table and are referenced from certain tables.

Comment: Exactly. It does not have to be that way, but I thought it is simple and intuitive.